# I want to get the error displayed when i load the file

Tags: php

```
<?php 
    class Errors {

        public $err=array();
        public function getError($p)
        {
            array_push($err,"$p");
        }
        public function displayError(){
            foreach ($err as $value) {
                echo "$value";
            }
        }
    }

    $m=new Errors();
    $m->getError("dghndvhdnbcf");
    $m->displayError();

 ?>
```

I am getting this errors on page.

> Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project01\errors.php on line 8
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: err in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project01\errors.php on line 12
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project01\errors.php on line 12

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: //<?php 
 
 class Errors {
  
  public $err=array();
  public function getError($p)
  {
   array_push($err,"$p");
  }

  public function displayError(){
   foreach ($err as $value) {
    echo "$value";
   }
  }
 }
 
 $m=new Errors();
 $m->getError("dghndvhdnbcf");
 $m->displayError();
 
 
  
 
  
 ?>

Comment: Please use [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52832681/edit) option to add the code to your question directly

Comment: `$this->err` not `$err`.

Comment: Do not edit your question with -wrongly- corrected code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a scope problem.

In this function, $err is undefined, because it belongs to the scope of the function.

```
public function getError($p)
{
    array_push($err,"$p");
}
```

If you want to use the `$err` property of the object, you have to use `$this` to indicate php that you are using an element of the current object.

Plus, the quotes around `$p` are superflu, this variable already being a string.

```
public function getError($p)
{
    array_push($this->err, $p);
}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'this' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)